# Cognos multipage bursting report

Tags: cognos, multipage

In Cognos I have three different SQL queries having data for 1 different month in one report.

I want to link 1 burst query with all the other 3 SQL queries.
Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried before or what part your stuck on.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code of SQL queries and the details of the target query?